# How can I call __strlen_sse2 from a C/C++ program? [Linux]

Tags: c++, c, linux, assembly

I'll state off the bat that I'm not a programmer, and am probably in over my head.

I'm trying to track down a bug in in the __strlen_sse2 (assembly) function installed in Debian as part of libc6-i686.

I already have a copy of the assembly code (.S file) and I need to figure out a way to call it from a C/C++ program. How can I achieve this?

edit:

Tried this code, but I get an error from gcc about undefined reference to '__strlen_sse2'

edit 2: It's my understanding that this is the proper answer to the question, but I lack the proper knowledge to carry it to completion. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t __strlen_sse2(const char *);

void main()
{
    char buffer[255];

    printf("Standby.. ");
    gets(buffer);
    __strlen_sse2("CRASH!");
    printf("OK!\n");
}
```

Like I said... not a programmer.

I hope my question makes sense. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly call the copy of `__strlen_sse2` inside the usual, dynamically-linked `/lib/libc.so.6` because it is a "hidden symbol" -- accessible to code inside libc itself, but not available for external linking.

You say you have the `.S` file that defines `__strlen_sse2`, from glibc's source code, but you're going to need to modify it to be buildable outside glibc.  I found what I think is the right file, and was able to modify it pretty easily.  Delete everything up to but not including the line that reads just

```
        .text
```

and replace it with this:

```
#define PUSH(REG)       pushl REG
#define POP(REG)        popl REG
#define PARMS           4
#define STR             PARMS
#define ENTRANCE
#define RETURN          ret
#define L(x)            .L##x
#define ENTRY(x)        .globl x; .type x,@function; x:
#define END(x)          .size x, .-x
```

Also delete the `#endif` line at the very end of the file.  Then compile like so:

```
gcc -m32 -c strlen-sse2.S
gcc -m32 -c test.c
gcc -m32 test.o strlen-sse2.o
./a.out
```

You may not need the `-m32`s.

You might be able to get some help with your larger problem from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) -- provide the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` in your question.

Comment: Wow, awesome answer. Thanks so much for the specific steps to achieve what I was after. Alas, seems like my bigger problem is not related to this specific function; but at least I was able to rule it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the function, preferably with a full prototype, and call it. This is probably the right prototype:

```
size_t __strlen_sse2(const char *);
```

I'm a bit skeptical of your claim that you're trying to track down a bug in this function. It's more likely there's a bug in your program that's calling `strlen` with an invalid argument (either an invalid pointer or a pointer to something other than a null-terminated string).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try this and report back. The programs that are crashing are actually init and bash. It's a complicated situation, but I just need to confirm that whatever the problem is, it happens inside of the libc, and is reproducible (at least on my system). That way I can make a proper bug report.

Comment: Tried your code, but the compiler complained about an undefined reference to the function. Please bear with me, this is new territory for me.

Comment: Was it the compiler or linker that complained? If it's the linker, that's probably because you didn't link to the file containing `__strlen_sse2`.

Comment: @jaquer: maybe the best starting point is to take a look when bash/init started to crash and what you (or someone else) did before that. maybe you have incompatible libc and binaries do to some manual update? Maybe the version of bash you're using was compiled with a different libc than what you now have installed on your system? for instance.

Comment: It also sounds like your dynamic linker might be misdetecting the cpu type and loading sse2 optimizations on a cpu that lacks sse2 instructions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure is some kind of hardware emulation incompatibility/issue, but I want to pinpoint exactly where the problem is so I can make an appropriate bug report. I don't want to turn the comments section into some kind of troubleshooting thread, since it's beyond the scope of my question. I'll accept your answer and keep trying to narrow down the problem. Thanks for your help.